# Password-protected Posts lead to 404 Error

Tags: posts, 404-error, password

I was just testing the password-protected posts functionality and when I submit the password it sends me to a 404 page. The password I typed in was correct, I made sure. The URL bar says: `www.mydomain.com/wp-pass.php` but shows a 404 page. Whether the password is correct or wrong, it should either show some message about it being wrong or the post that was protected. Not just a 404 page.

What could be causing this? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Does your browser send a `Referer` header?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. Could you explain?

Comment: See `wp-pass.php`: `wp_safe_redirect(wp_get_referer());` If your browser does not send a [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) you might get problems. Your browser offers a debugger where you can see the network communication.

Comment: So this is something specific to the browser that is being used to view the website and not Wordpress itself? I use Firefox 17, but I also tested it in Chrome 23 and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Some proxies are stripping the referer too, no matter what browser you are using. I don’t know if that is the cause for your problem. It could be.

Comment: I don't use proxies or anything of that kind. I've also tried it on iPod Touch Safari and it's the same thing. Is it likely that something theme-related could cause a problem like this?

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Comment: Deactivated all plugins and tested on TwentyEleven. Works fine. So it's something to do with the theme and I have no idea what it could be...do you have any idea what in themes could cause something like this? Anyway, thanks so far. I guess I'll get back to this thread when I've figured anything out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out myself! I had used add_filter to customize the password form in order to add css classes. Everything in add_filter was either old or simply wrong. I found it in a tutorial, but this has been a lesson to me. Never trust code found on the web unless it from the Codex or an absolute expert.

EDIT: Just found the same piece of code in the Codex as well *facepalm. It says "THIS NO LONGER WORKS" above it, but then why is it still in the codex? To anyone having this problem as well: in case you have used the code from here: [Using Password Protection: Password Form Text](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection#Password_Form_Text) you'll get problems in newer versions of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

mfw when the right answer from Wombat has -3

Sorry for not commenting but I don't have any repo here yet and am really just wondering what's going on on wordpress.stackexchange.com

What exactly should Wombat add to this? We have a WP installation with some old code (meanwhile codex should be correct for the current WP version) from codex.wordpress.com in our Theme's `functions.php` file to customize the password form for example like this:

```
<?php
function my_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-pass.php', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post">
    ' . __( "To view this protected post, enter the password below:" ) . '
    <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    ';
    return $o;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
?>
```

On some update WP changed the form but as we overwrite it with our filter in our `functions.php` we now get the error described by the OP after the update in question. And now we change `wp-pass.php` to `/wp-login.php?action=postpass` just like Wombat said (and like shown on the current codex page) like this:

```
<?php
function my_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post">
    ' . __( "To view this protected post, enter the password below:" ) . '
    <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    ';
    return $o;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
?>
```

Problem solved.
(For anyone who already implemented a custom filter which caused this problem this should be no problem with the information Wombat provided... so why the heck do you guys down rate him??)

Comment: Welcome on WPSE Jey. The problem is that he isn't adding any explanation, context and alike. Please have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I kinda know the rules for answers. But it's not helpful at all when due to 'bureaucracy', if you will, a correct answer gets down rated. I was here because I had the problem with an old WP site which got updated recently and as the post(s) of charlenemasters and its comments were not very helpful I had to figure out on my own what the problem was (I didn't read Wombat because of the -3). And when I found the problem I had the feeling I have seen the solution before, came back here and read Wombat; doing so in the first place would have saved me some time - and maybe other googlers, too...

Answer (score -2):

Change the instance of wp-pass.php to /wp-login.php?action=postpass

Comment: Please add more detail to this answer.